# Using a MessageGroupStoreReaper with an Aggregator

Tags: spring, spring-integration, declarative, reaper

The reference documentation recommends using a reaper with an aggregator in order to prevent memory leaks due to stacked-up MessageGroup metadata.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator

Is this always the case, that a reaper is necessary? Or is there a combination of aggregator attributes like `expire-groups-upon-completion` and/or `expire-groups-upon-timeout` that can set up conditions such that MessageGroup data is removed?

thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation is correct. The `expire-groups-upon-completion` ensures that completed groups are removed from the store. The `expire-groups-upon-timeout`, in combination with a `group-timeout`, does similar to the reaper functionality. Also, if you use a persistent store for the `MessageGroupStore`, then all your group are unloaded from the memory to DB.